# Missing adminsortable models module in my django project

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I have the following lines in my models.py file:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models
from adminsortable.models import Sortable
from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderField
from filer.fields.image import FilerImageField

class StaffMember(Sortable):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'staff'
    full_name = models.CharField(u'full name',
        blank=False,
        default='',
        help_text=u'Please enter a full name for this staff member',
        max_length=64,
        unique=True,
    )

slug = models.SlugField(u'slug',
    blank=False,
    default='',
    help_text=u'Provide a unique slug for this staff member',
    max_length=64,
)

seniority = models.ForeignKey('staff.Seniority',
    blank=True,
    default=None,
    help_text=u'Please specify a seniority level for this staff member',
    null=True
)
photo = FilerImageField(
    blank=True,
    help_text=u'Optional. Please supply a photo of this staff member.',
    null=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL, # Important
)
bio = PlaceholderField('staff_bio')
def absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('staff:staffmember_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug, })
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.full_name
```

When i do a syncdb, i am getting this error:

```
File "/home/abhishek/workspace/djangocms/staff/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from adminsortable.models import Sortable
ImportError: No module named adminsortable.models
```

From where do i get this module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you try to build. but it seems like you are missing a package.
Think you should take a look at this: https://github.com/iambrandontaylor/django-admin-sortable

pretty sure that is the one you are missing

```
pip install django-admin-sortable
```